# Search and replace hundreds of strings in tens of thousands of files?

Tags: regex, replace

I am looking into changing the file name of hundreds of files in a (C/C++) project that I work on. The problem is our software has tens of thousands of files that including (i.e. #include) these hundreds of files that will get changed. This looks like a maintenance nightmare. If I do this I will be stuck in Ultra-Edit for weeks, rolling hundreds of regex's by hand like so:

```
^\#include.*["<\\/]stupid_name.*$
```

with

```
#include <dir/new_name.h>
```

Such drudgery would be worse than peeling hundreds of potatoes in a sunken submarine in the antarctic with a spoon.
I think it would rather be ideal to put the inputs and outputs into a table like so:

```
stupid_name.h <-> <dir/new_name.h>
stupid_nameb.h <-> <dir/new_nameb.h>
stupid_namec.h <-> <dir/new_namec.h>
```

and feed this into a regular expression engine / tool / app / etc...

**My Ultimate Question**: Is there a tool that will do that?

**Bonus Question**: Is it multi-threaded?

I looked at quite a few search and replace topics here on this website, and found lots of standard queries that asked a variant of the following question:

**standard question**: Replace one term in N files.

as opposed to:

**my question**: Replace N terms in N files.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Can you provide some real examples of before and after names (and maybe more of them - say 20 or so)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Wilkins says, this is a workable plan with whatever regex-handy scripting tool you prefer, but I'd suggest a couple of additional points:

1. Use two scripts: one to translate your list into a regexes, and another to apply them. Trying to do both jobs in one script is asking for trouble.

   Don't forget to change the #include directives and rename the header files at the same time.

   If you know how to change one thing in N files, then, heck, you can just loop over the K things you want to change. It's not the most efficient way in terms of processor time, but that's not the bottleneck here.

   This approach will work in theory, but if it works in practice on the first try then your code base is cleaner than anything (that size) I've ever seen. There will almost certainly be little surprises: a hard-coded path that doesn't match the regex, a bad name that collides with a good name, some other glitch nobody would have thought of. I suggest starting small, with one or two pairs of names, compiling after every replacement, and retreating in case of trouble. If you do this right you can set it up to run overnight and in the morning you'll have a working code base that's almost done, and a list of the names that caused trouble and need human attention.

Comment: Good point about #2 above. I was so used to doing this manually that I neglected to think about that. When I did this previously (manually), I has having to rename the files by hand in perforce. That was very tedious. I'll have to script up that too.

Answer (score 2):

I would use awk, a command line tool similar to sed.

```
mv file.x file.x.bak;
awk '{
  gsub( "#include \"bad_one.h\"" , "#include \"good_one.h\"" );
  gsub( "#include \"bad_two.h\"" , "#include \"good_two.h\"" );
}' file.x.bak > file.x;
```

Once you are at a terminal, use `man awk` to see more details.

Comment: Thanks: that code is certainly terse and to the point, that's for sure. It certainly leaves a little bit of scripting to do around that snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea of putting the old/new names into a single location is a good one.  It would certainly reduce the difficulty of maintaining and verifying the changes.  It seems like this is the obvious answer, but I think that using any of the popular scripting languages such as ruby, python, perl, etc. would make this task fairly straightforward.  The script could read in the file that has the old/new replacement information, construct the appropriate regular expressions from that, and then process the files that need the replacements.

The script could be written as a multi-threaded utility, although it doesn't seem like there would be a lot of benefit in this type of situation.  If I understand the question, this should be basically a one-time usage so high performance does not seem like the top priority.

Comment: If I fail to find an available solution, I'll just to write my own. I'm comfortable in any of those scripting languages you specified. Oh, I forgot to add, that all those thousands of files are under version control too. :)
And your point about the necessity of being multi-threaded is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Make a series of perl one-liners to edit the files in place, like so:

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's/stupid_old_name/cool_new_name/' *.c
```

This has the added bonus of saving the originals of any changed files with a .bak extension.

I'd make a bunch of these, if I didn't know perl that well.  I'd even put all the one-liners into a shell script, but then I'm not trying to impress any of the unix graybeards out there.

This website explains edit in place with perl very well:
http://www.rice.edu/web/perl-edit.html

PS - Since I do know perl fairly well, I'd just write the was/is table in a "real" perl script and use it to open and parse all the files.

Comment: Thanks. I agree, I would have to write a real perl script if I was to realistically use this.

Answer (score 0):

Will [this](http://www.wingrep.com/) (Wingrep) do the trick?

Comment: It would, but it only searches for one thing at a time... in multiple files. So that is the case of: Replace one thing in N amount of files. I need to replace multiple things in multiple files.
Ultra Edit (My desert island programming tool) can already do that very well.

Answer (score 0):

in *nix, (or GNU win32) , you can use GNU find and sed together... eg

```
find /path -type f -name "*.c" -exec  sed -i.bak 's/^\#include.*["<\\/]stupid_name.*$/#include <dir\/new_name.h>/' "{}" +;
```

explanation,

the `find` command starts finding files (`-type f`)  starting from `/path`. `-name "*.c"` searches for all `.c` files, then for each one found, do a `sed` to change the string to the new string. `-i.bak` asks `sed` to save the original file as backup before doing inplace editing. `"{}"` means the file passed to `sed`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what GNU win32 is?

Comment: they are mostly *nix tools ported to windows. See here gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html

Comment: Could you add an explanation of all the little parts that make up your code sample would be great.

Answer (score 0):

[PowerGREP](http://www.powergrep.com) can do that. It can search for multiple search strings (literal text or regular expressions) in any combination of files, and is multithreaded (starting with PowerGREP 4, the current version).

[alt text http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/5172/screen006c.png](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/5172/screen006c.png)

You can save your searches for later re-use, too.

Comment: Ah, a deal breaker:
From their website: "Most grep tools can only search for a single regular expression. With PowerGREP you can use up to five sets of search terms."

Comment: I have tried it and successfully entered dozens of search terms (>>100), so perhaps that limitation is no longer there. Are the names and their replacements that individually different that you really need hundreds of different regexes? I find that hard to believe.